# Why does a specific numpy implementation of the Gauss-Jacobi method significantly reduce iterations?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

When implementing the Gauss Jacobi algorithm in python I found that two different implementations take a significantly different number of iterations to converge.

The first implementation is what I originally came up with

```py
import numpy as np
def GaussJacobi(A, b, x, x_solution, tol):
    k = 0
    N = A.shape[0]
    D = np.diag(A)
    R = A-np.diagflat(D);
    while(checkTol(tol, x, x_solution)):
        x_new = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.double) #x(k+1)
        for i in range(N):
            aii = D[i]
            bi = b[i]
            s = np.dot(R[i], x)
            x_n[i] = (1/aii)*(bi - s)
        x = x_new
        k+=1
        print('x(%d) =' % k, x)
    return k
```

The second implementation is based on [this article.](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Jacobi-Method-in-Python-and-NumPy/)

```
def GaussJacobi(A, b, x, x_solution, tol):
    k = 0
    N = A.shape[0]
    D = np.diag(A)
    R = A-np.diagflat(D);
    while(checkTol(tol, x, x_solution)):
        for i in range(N):
            x = (b - np.dot(R, x)) / D
        k+=1
        print('x(%d) =' % k, x)
    return k
```

When solving the following problem

```
A = [ 4, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0]
    [-1,  4, -1,  0, -1,  0]
    [ 0, -1,  4,  0,  0, -1]
    [-1,  0,  0,  4, -1,  0]
    [0,  -1,  0, -1,  4, -1]
    [0,   0, -1,  0, -1,  4] 

b = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]

x_solution =[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

x0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The first implementation takes 37 iterations to converge with an error of 1e-8 while the second implementation takes only 7 iterations to converge.

What makes the second implementation so much faster than the first?

**EDIT:**

I've implemented two other methods, the Gauss-Seidel Method and the SOR method. Both of these were implemented in a similar way to my original, slow Gauss-Jacobi method.

I ran randomized tests on 100 NxN Diagonally dominant matrices for each N = 4...20 to get an average number of iterations until convergence.

```
  N    Gauss-Jacobi    Gauss-Jacobi Fast    Gauss Seidel    SOR -- w=1.5
---  --------------  -------------------  --------------  --------------
  4           40.96                17.04         40.6804         40.9204
  5           49.11                17.25         48.7489         48.9389
  6           56.11                16.04         55.6789         55.9089
  7           70.26                18            69.6774         70.0074
  8           76.4                 16.54         75.756          76.236
  9           83.56                17.03         82.8344         83.1044
 10           92.33                16.24         91.5267         91.7267
 11           98.02                16.59         97.1598         97.4598
 12          107.39                15.98        106.436         106.756
 13          123.48                17.75        122.375         122.655
 14          125.07                16.04        123.949         124.239
 15          132.41                16.68        131.206         131.496
 16          145                   16.31        143.67          143.91
 17          149.66                16.75        148.283         148.493
 18          154.21                15.58        152.788         153.078
 19          163.18                16.51        161.668         161.918
 20          167.58                15.38        166.014         166.254
```

The faster Gauss Jacobi implementation is not only significantly faster than every other implementation, but it does not seem to increase with array size like the other methods.

When inspecting the methods as they are running it seems like the fast method creates a very good guess on its first iteration.

My guess is that it has to do something with the `np.dot` function, but I don't understand why this would work differently than doing each dot product independently.

Comment: have you tried more randomized inputs to benchmark the two algorithms?

Comment: The dot products in the two implementations are quite different. In the first, you are multiplying `x` with a different row of `R` on each iteration, while the second is an actual iteration, `R*(...(R*(R*x))...)`

Answer (score 1):

Your second implementation does `N` *actual* iterations per increment of `k`, since the assignment to `x` already covers the **entire** vector.  Its “advantage” thus increases with problem size.